# Multiple Steps on WHEN NOT MATCHED possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I have a sequence I need to use to recalculate both fields in the primary key if an update match isn't found. Is it possible to still use the MERGE statement here? I tried WHEN MATCHED THEN BEGIN, but BEGIN isn't valid here.

Specifically, I have a pair of numbers that make up the primary key. The first is a grouping, and the second is a sequence of items within the group. If something goes wrong,  the group comes in as 99990, and I need to combine it with the sequence and use a sequence to increment, then split it back apart. So, when the group comes in with 99990, my calculated groups can range from 99990 through 99999, and the sequence number will then range from 00 through 99.

I can't think of a way to do this as part of the INSERT assignment, and I can't figure out how to make the MERGE do multiple steps, so I'm guessing I'm back to UPDATE, IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BEGIN. Anyone have a faster way to do this?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Judging by the `@@rowcount` probably SQL Server?

Comment: It's SQL Server, just as you surmised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to do multiple steps in a MERGE. Sometimes the new Common Table Expression syntax can be used, but I resorted to an UPDATE, IF @@ROWcOUNT = 0, INSERT so I could do multiple steps on the insert.

Answer (score 3):

This works,

1. Declare a flag variable (bit) called @isinsert
2. Initialize it with the value of 1.
3. On the update clause set it to 0.

Like this: (assuming a table called table1 with a numeric 'id' field and an nvarchar 'field1' field).

```
declare @id numeric(18,0)                  -- That's the he lookup key 
set @id=999                                -- We use id as the search key
                                           -- You can use any other field    
declare @field nvarchar(50)
set @field = 'insert or update value(s)'   -- This is the new value

declare @isinsert bit                      -- This is a flag that will
set @isinsert=1                            -- indicate whether an insert or 
                                           -- an update were performed 

MERGE table1 AS target
    USING (SELECT @field) AS source (field1)
    ON (target.id = @id)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET field1 = source.field1
        ,@isinsert = 0                     -- Set @isinsert to 0 on updates
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   
        INSERT (field1)
        VALUES (source.field1);

if (@isinsert=1) print concat('inserted record at id: ',@@IDENTITY)
else print concat('updated record at id: ',@id)
```

Comment: Kewl. I haven't had time to grok this yet, but it looks interesting. I suspect I'm going to learn something new. In that spirit, I'm up-voting this. It's too late to use it, but it's never too late to learn something new. Thanks.